# What functions are used when the system call fork() is called

Tags: linux, kernel, fork

I've been searching through the net to find what functions are used inside the fork.c and in what order, however I can't seem to find the answer. All I see is what fork.c does. I know that fork.c uses _do_fork() but how it gets there I don't know.

Comment: How what gets where?

Answer (score 0):

When **fork()** system call is made it creates a new process by duplicating the calling process. And new process will be called the **child** process.

Look at this code its basic overview.

```
fork()->sys_fork()->do_fork()

sys_fork()
{
 1. First it will validate the arguments.
 2. Invoke do_fork.
 3. return pid. (child pid)
}

do_fork()
{
1. First it will Allocate new address space.
2. Copy Segments of Caller address space to new address space.
3. allocate new task_struct instance. (PCB)
4. copy caller task_struct entries to new task_struct.
5. return.
}
```

On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child.

**Note:** Their Are some few more calls but these two are most important and if you want to know more look into kernel source. If Still need help let me know.